# traefik dnsChallenge and httpChallenge (backup) simultaneously

Tags: docker, traefik

I want to use the dnsChallenge for domains, that i have at Cloudflare and if that fails i want to use the httpChallenge. Is that possible with traefik?

The error:

```
traefik    | time="2018-05-05T18:33:03Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \"www.example.org,example.org\" detected thanks to rule \"Host:www.example.org,example.org\" : cannot obtain certificates map[example.org:Error presenting token: Zone example.org. not found in CloudFlare for domain _acme-challenge.example.org. www.example.org:Error presenting token: Zone example.org. not found in CloudFlare for domain _acme-challenge.www.example.org.]"
```

My config looks like this.

```
debug = false
logLevel = "WARN"
defaultEntryPoints = ["https","http"]

# Entrypoints, http and https
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
  [entryPoints.https.tls]

# Enable ACME (Let's Encrypt): automatic SSL
[acme]
email = "admin@xxx"
storage = "/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
onDemand = false
OnHostRule = true

  [acme.httpChallenge]
  entryPoint = "http"

  [acme.dnsChallenge]
  provider = "cloudflare"
  delayBeforeCheck = 0

[[acme.domains]]
  main = "*.sub.example.com"
  sans = ["sub.example.com"]

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
watch = true
exposedbydefault = false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, it's not possible to use the both challenges at the same time.

Comment: Hi Idez, do you have any updates on this? Is it still not possible?